# Efficiency with VB.NET Code

Tags: vb.net, performance, optimization

If I had code like this:

```
Public Module Global_Variables
  Public Stuff as string
End Module

Public Class Stuff_Doer
  Me.TextBox1.Text = Global_Variables.Stuff
End Class
```

Would it be more efficient to do this:

```
Public Module Global_Variables
  Public Stuff as string
End Module

Public Class Stuff_Doer
  Me.TextBox1.Text = Stuff
End Class
```

Or would it be the same as the program would just it behind the scenes anyway?

Comment: This is not an answer, but note that the memory load for Stuff is incredibly tiny compared to updating a UI control and painting. 5 orders of magnitude? Probably more.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is no name conflict for `Stuff`, they are the same program and result in the same IL.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That is what I thought, but I was making sure that what out saying where the variable was if it was doing something else and slowing down the program.

Answer (score 0):

They would result in the same program after compile-time optimizations have occurred.

You shouldn't really consider optimizing something as small as this, even if they were different the difference would absolutely tiny, too small to measure accurately.